# Slicing data by dynamic variable names in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large number of data files which take this basic shape:

```
userID <- c(rep(10001, 3), rep(10002, 3), rep(10003, 3))
theValue <- c(NA, "foo", NA, "foo", "bar", NA, "foo", "bar", "foo_and_bar") 

(rawData <- tibble(userID, theValue))

    # A tibble: 9 x 2
  userID theValue   
   <dbl> <chr>      
1  10001 NA         
2  10001 foo        
3  10001 NA         
4  10002 foo        
5  10002 bar        
6  10002 NA         
7  10003 foo        
8  10003 bar        
9  10003 foo_and_bar
```

My goal is, a list of the distinct non-NA values that each user ID can have associated with it:

```
(df <- rawData %>%
  filter(!is.na(theValue)) %>%
  group_by(userID) %>%
  distinct(theValue))

   theValue    userID
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 foo          10001
2 foo          10002
3 bar          10002
4 foo          10003
5 bar          10003
6 foo_and_bar  10003
```

And I will also be asked to slice those results by certain userIDs...

```
df[df$userID == 10001, ]

 theValue userID
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 foo       10001
```

...or perhaps to treat userID like a factor:

```
df$userID <- as.factor(df$userID)
```

Here's the problem: in many of my files, the first column is not always called "userID". It can be called "userID-A", or "userID_1", or "SoylentGreen" ... anything.

I can do most of my code dynamically:

```
theID <- "userID"
IDsymbol <- as.symbol(theID)

df2 <- rawData %>%
  filter(!is.na(theValue)) %>%
  group_by(!!IDsymbol) %>%
  distinct(theValue)

identical(df2, df)
[1] TRUE
```

But I have no idea how to do the slicing or the factor-assignation. I've looked at some "programming for dplyr" websites, but I'm not sure which of the solutions listed apply to my case. Here are some sample codes which I have tried...

```
df2[theID == 10001, ]
df2[!!IDsymbol == 10001, ]
df2$!!IDsymbol <- as.factor(df2$!!IDsymbol)
```

...but they all return either errors or empty datasets. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `group_by_at` which takes string as input and `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)
rawData %>% 
   filter(complete.cases(theValue)) %>%
   group_by_at(theID) %>% 
   distinct(theValue) %>% 
   filter_at(vars(theID), any_vars(. == 10001))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# Groups:   userID [1]
#  theValue userID
#  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 foo       10001
```

---

Or by converting to symbol (`sym`) and evaluate (`!!`)

```
rawData %>%
     filter(complete.cases(theValue)) %>%
     group_by(!! rlang::sym(theID)) %>% 
     distinct(theValue) %>% 
     filter(!! rlang::sym(theID) == 10001)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# Groups:   userID [1]
# theValue userID
#  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 foo       10001
```

---

The issue in the OP's code is trying to apply `tidyverse` methods outside the tidyverse environment i.e. in `base R`.